# Background transition with sprite image in css3?

Tags: html, css

Any one please give me the correct approach to do this using `css3`?

1) I have on bg image it contains multiple `states` of each sprite.

i am using keyframe animation to update the each of the position of backgroud, but it not come well

How to do it? if am not wrong any one show the correct way please?

my code :

```
<div class="bg"></div>

div.bg {
    background : url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10268257/all.png) 0 center;
    height:443px;
    width:795px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animateBg {
    0%{ background-position :0px center}
    5.882352941176471%{ background-position :795px center}
    11.764705882352942%{ background-position :1590px center}
    17.647058823529413%{ background-position :2385px center}
    23.529411764705884%{ background-position :3180px center}
    29.411764705882355%{ background-position :3975px center}
    35.294117647058826%{ background-position :4770px center}
    41.1764705882353%{ background-position :5565px center}
    47.05882352941177%{ background-position :6360px center}
    52.94117647058824%{ background-position :7155px center}
    58.82352941176471%{ background-position :7950px center}
    64.70588235294119%{ background-position :8745px center}
    70.58823529411765%{ background-position :9540px center}
    76.47058823529412%{ background-position :10335px center}
    82.3529411764706%{ background-position :11130px center}
    88.23529411764707%{ background-position :11925px center}
    23 94.11764705882354%{ background-position :12720px center}
}

div.bg:hover {
      animation-name: animateBg;  
      animation-duration: 4s;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oe27u6sq/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's because you need to define the number of steps and then just put the animation as the total length, it will divide it up itself.

(change the '1s' to speed up or slow down the animation)

```
div.bg {
    background : url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10268257/all.png);
    height:443px;
    width:795px;
    -webkit-animation: animateBg 1s steps(16) infinite;
       -moz-animation: animateBg 1s steps(16) infinite;
        -ms-animation: animateBg 1s steps(16) infinite;
         -o-animation: animateBg 1s steps(16) infinite;
            animation: animateBg 1s steps(16) infinite;
    margin:0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animateBg {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -12720px; }
}

@-moz-keyframes animateBg {
       from { background-position:    0px; }
         to { background-position: -12720px; }
}

@-ms-keyframes animateBg {
       from { background-position:    0px; }
         to { background-position: -12720px; }
}

@-o-keyframes animateBg {
       from { background-position:    0px; }
         to { background-position: -12720px; }
}

@keyframes animateBg {
       from { background-position:    0px; }
         to { background-position: -12720px; }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oe27u6sq/5/

and on:hover
http://jsfiddle.net/oe27u6sq/6/

Comment: As a information, I need to require a function should be called on some point say, 10th frame - how to do that?

Comment: do you mean you want to activate a javascript function on the 'nth' frame of the css animation?
I'm unsure how you would listen for the change in CSS to trigger the function but it seems there are plugins that might help

http://meetselva.github.io/attrchange/

i would listen to the changes in css and on a certain background-position number activate the function but this might be considered a separate question

Answer (score 1):

you need use steps

```
div.bg {
    background : url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10268257/all.png) 0 center;
    height:443px;
    width:795px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animateBg {
    100%{ background-position: 15900px center}
}

div.bg:hover {
  animation: animateBg 2s steps(20) infinite;
}
```

step num the images and the image size in the keyFrame 100%

About prefixing

```
@-webkit-keyframes animateBg {
    0% {background-position: 0px center}
    100%{ background-position: 15900px center}
}

@keyframes animateBg {
    0% {background-position: 0px center}
    100%{ background-position: 15900px center}
}

div.bg:hover {
  -webkit-animation: animateBg 2s steps(20) infinite; /* Chr, Saf */
          animation: animateBg 2s steps(20) infinite; /* IE >9, Fx >15, Op >12.0 */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p65j4oar/